# Bash script - Command not found error on consuming Python output

Tags: python, bash

I've a bash script, which calls a python script. Python script returns me an object, which I then assign to a variable in bash and have to return.

I am getting command not found when I try to eval the output of the python script. Bash is treating it as a command instead of a value.

Below is the code:

```
function myfunc()
{
    local  __resultvar=$1
    local  myresult=$(/home/centos/pentaho2.py)
    eval $__resultvar="'$myresult'"
}

myfunc result
echo $result
```

My python command returns me a value like this:

```
[('quatre vingt douze ave des champs-élysées', 'road')]
```

After executing the script, I see this error:

```
./pentaho2.sh: line 5: vingt: command not found
```

Could someone help me understand what am I missing here?

Comment: Have you got #!/usr/bin/python at the start of the Python script? The path needs to be the actual path on your local system.

Comment: Hi @RamanSailopal , yes I've python path present in my script: #!/usr/bin/env python3

Comment: The result of your python command contains quotes, which most likely causes the error. I  recommend avoiding the whole eval business, as that can cause you a lot of grief if you are new to bash. If you goal is to return some string from a function you should consider using the sub-process approach or simply assigning to a global variable, as those are generally easier to work.

Answer (score 1):

If your bash version is 4.3 or greater, using a nameref in your function allows you to avoid `eval` and the inherent quoting problems

```sh
myfunc() {
    local -n __resultvar=$1
    __resultvar=$(/home/centos/pentaho2.py)
}

myfunc result
echo "$result"
```

To see the error in action, use `set -x`:

```sh
myresult="[('quatre vingt douze ave des champs-élysées', 'road')]"
set -x
eval result="'$myresult'"
```

output

```
+ eval 'result='\''[('\''quatre vingt douze ave des champs-élysées'\'', '\''road'\'')]'\'''
++ result='[(quatre'
++ vingt douze ave des 'champs-élysées, road)]'
```

A quoting problem indeed.

---

An alternative is to use `declare` instead of `eval`

```sh
$ __resultvar=result
$ declare "$__resultvar=$myresult"
$ declare -p result
declare -- result="[('quatre vingt douze ave des champs-élysées', 'road')]"
```

Comment: `printf -v "$1" "%s" "$(/home/centos/pentaho2.py)"` is also an option.